# how do you change jpeg export quality in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

e.g. if i want to export a jpeg at 80%, how do i do that in Sketch.app? it appears to export at 96% by default.

Answer (score 7):

edit:

there is a much more simple way of doing this. when you hit export and the file prompt shows up, click options, and you are presented with options including quality

[image]

---

after some investigation, i discovered you are able to do this via os x's command line `defaults` tool:

to lower the quality:

```
$ defaults write com.bohemiancoding.sketch3 JPGQuality -string "0.6"
```

you can reset it to the default of 0.9:

```
$ defaults write com.bohemiancoding.sketch3 JPGQuality -string "0.9"
```

i also learned that a variety of things can affect JPEG quality, so the percentage i set in sketch doesn't line up exactly with the quality reported by imagemagick's identify tool.

you can see Sketch's configurations by running this command:

```
$ defaults read com.bohemiancoding.sketch3
```

Comment: Amazing! Is there any way to set these defaults per-project?

Comment: @JacobFord i can't say for sure, but i doubt it ✌

Comment: @JacobFord i found a much more simple way of doing this that would probably suit your needs (click "Options" on the file chooser screen)

Comment: Oh! Well that was obvious.

Comment: To see your current .jpg setting in sketch, do what @PETER said (sweet!), but tack this on to the end of your terminal command `defaults read com.bohemiancoding.sketch3 | grep -i jpg` That returns any lines with "jpg" in them. The `-i` option makes the search case insensitive.